# dd MBR and one partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, dd

I have 2 partitions on a drive and I need to use dd to create a new image of just the MBR and second partition. Here is the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`

```
Device        Start        End        Blocks
/dev/sda1     2048         7813119    3905536
/dev/sda2     7813120      15626239   3906560
```

The partition I need to backup is `/dev/sda2`. I have an image of the partition itself from running `dd if=/dev/sda2 of=part2.img bs=1M`. I have created `mbr.img` by running `dd if=/dev/sda of=mbr.img bs=1M count=1`

If I concatenate `part2.img` to the end of `mbr.img`, how can I modify the MBR of the resulting image to contain the correct start and end blocks?

Answer (score 0):

MBR is only 512 first bytes of a disk. Unless it is (U)EFI. Combining the MBR and the image would be very complicated, even after MBR edition. The question is, what you want to do with the image later. You would need to make exactly the same (size) partition to restore it from the image and then you would not need to mess with the MBR.